# Query with wrong result JPA Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem and it is that a `@Query` to the database does not get me the correct results.

In WorkBench with this query: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE FECHA_INICIO >= '2020-02-01' AND FECHA_FIN <= '2020-02-28'`, returns a total of 18 results.

But with my JAVA code, it only shows 6 records and they are the ones that in the column `FECHA_INICIO` have `2020-02-01` and in the `FECHA_FIN` column they have the value `2020-02-28`. The records that in any of these columns have a date that does not correspond to the last day of the month or first, do not show them. That's the problem.

This is my JAVA code from the repository:

```
public interface TableRepository extends CrudRepository<Table, String> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE FECHA_INICIO >= :fechaInicio AND FECHA_FIN <= :fechaFin", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Table> findAllBetweenDates(@Param("fechaInicio") Date fechaInicio, @Param("fechaFin") Date fechaFin);
}
```

I tried to see what query the code was doing but in the logs it only showed me the following:

```
org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement - SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FECHA_INICIO >= ? AND FECHA_FIN <= ?
```

Both columns in the database are of type Date. Add that this code if it works for me in a copy of the database that I have in PostgreSQL, but in MySQL it is where it only shows me the 6 records instead of the 18. Any idea what might be going on?

**EDIT:**

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table")
public class Table{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", length = 20)
    @NotNull
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "FECHA_INICIO")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @NotNull
    private Date fechaInicio;

    @Column(name = "FECHA_FIN")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @NotNull
    private Date fechaFin;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 20)
    @NotNull
    private String descripcion;
}
```

Comment: The Date in your repository is java.util.Date or java.sql.Date? Also, what is the type used for date in your Entity?

Comment: In my Entity and in the repository is java.util.Date @RitikaGoel

Comment: Can you pls share the structure of your entity also?

Comment: Sure @RitikaGoel

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood so far, you are using `java.util.date` in your entity and repository. Please make sure you have annotated the date fields in your entity with `@Temporal(TemporalType.Date)`.

Also,  I am assuming your java version is 8 or higher. If this is the case, it would be worth giving `java.time.LocalDate` a try. :)

Hope this will help!

**EDIT:** I tried with a local setup today. Though I could not replicate your specific problem, but I have a few observations when I ran the code in debugging mode -

1. Connection URL for MySQL needs timezone info `serverTimezone=UTC`. When I did not provide this info, it gave me exceptions while server was starting up.
2. With `java.util.Date` in the controller the request gets parsed with the time zone. So for below shown controller, if I use startDate=2019-01-01 it translated to January 1, 2019 05:30IST i.e. it had my local timezone info.

   `@GettMapping(value = "/test")
   public List<Test> getResult(
      @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate startDate,
      @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate endDate) {
       List<Test> result = testService.getResult(startDate, endDate);
       return result;
   }`

Based on the above observations, I feel the problem maybe caused because of the timezone being picked.

Thereafter, I changed `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDate` in Controller, Service, Entity and Repository. Also, I removed `@Temporal(TemporalType.Date)` from my entity. This time in debugging only date got picked.

**Can you pls try using `java.time.LocalDate` in your code and share the results. Also, do make the changes to your entity as I mentioned in the comment section! **

**P.S. - This might not resolve your problem completely, but will definitely help in debugging further.**

Comment: Looking at the entity ot aeems you have done everything correctly. Can you please tell me the DB datatype for these columns? I'll do a local setup tomorrow and try to reproduce this at my end!

Comment: In the DB the colums type is DATE

Comment: Hey, few things to take care while creating entity - it should implement Serializable interface for REST APIs, should have all argument and no argument constructor and getters and setters should be present.

Comment: I have it implemented, only since they were obvious things (for me) I did not put them

Comment: Actually that's what I thought! :) Sorry if my comment sounded other way around!

Answer (score 0):

It´s very probably that you are comparing the date plus the time and some rows are being filtered.

Example:

2020-04-23 **15:00**

2020-04-23 **01:00**

You can use the following function to formatted your date (startDate and endDate) before to execute the query

```
private Date getFormattedFromDateTime(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

And like @Ritika said: please try to use java.time.* it is far better than java.util.*

Comment: This did not work for me. I don't know the reason but if instead of passing the dates 2020-02-01 and 2020-02-28, I pass the dates 2020-01-31 and 2020-03-01 if it takes out all the records I need. It is as if the query was not taking the = in the <=

Comment: Maybe the issue is not about **this** query, but about the moment that you are inserting the records. you should check the date object just before to be saved. I am sure it is a timezone problem. Also, check the url connection if you are using serverTimeZone=UTC, you can play with this value (change it to actual timezone) and try again. I hope this works for you!